# Extensions by recursive definitions

Tags: logic, arithmetic, recurrence-relations

In the Wikipedia entry on [Extension by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_by_definitions)s I learn that an *explicit* definition in the language of a theory $T$ yields a [conservative extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_extension) $T'$ of $T$.

I wonder if this eventually does not hold for *recursive* definitions or why the statement is not made more generally.

> Is it true that any *recursive* definition in the language of a theory
>   $T$ which allows recursive definitions yields a conservative extension $T'$ of $T$?

Comment: By "recursive definition" do you mean "implicit definition"?

Comment: I mean definitions like that of addition in first-order Peano arithmetic: in the form of two axioms which together with the induction schema yield all relevant properties of addition. (That means: recursive definitions work only in the presence of induction?)

Comment: Please note that I restricted my question to theories *which allow recursive definitions* (which implies that they have induction axioms?)

Comment: Interesting question, I am also interested to know this.